# Apache logs showing strange ^@ characters ? What does this mean ?

Tags: apache, lamp

My apache logs are always interrupted by strange characters :

```
84.196.205.238, 172.23.20.177, 172.23.20.177 - - [05/May/2015:11:48:15 +0200] 0 www.sudinfo.be "GET /sites/default/files/imagecache/pagallery_450x300/552495393_google_street_view HTTP/1.1" 200 32620 "http://www.sudinfo.be/247263/article/culture/medias/2011-11-23/google-street-view-en%C2%A0belgique-comment-trouver-votre-maison" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; nl-be; GT-P3110 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.30"
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@efault/files/imagecache/pagallery_450x300/2015/01/13/1554554859_B974505865Z.1_20150113094316_000_GVR3PDRHQ.1-0.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 26033 "http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=leonardo+dicaprio+Met+gala&id=06B1C7410D6458C6A698AC09F3F8C6B7915BFFDE&FORM=IQFRBA" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53"
```

Do you have any idea what can be the cause of this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your web server is externally accessible then this is probably an artifact from an attempt to hack your server

ISTR `^@` is how apache logs a "NULL" zero byte.  These are used to pad attacks such as buffer overflow

You may like to look at counter measures such as mod_security

https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/ModSecurity-Frequently-Asked-Questions-%28FAQ%29

I hope it is obvious that a full patched server and application stack is more likely to be able to withstand random attack attempts like this

Comment: I thought it was something vicious too. Thanks a lot for your input, I'll investigate this further.

Comment: This was just a network problem; see my answer below ;) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally found out what the problem was. My log files are written on a Network filesystem and my bash client just had problems to read it because of the network.

False alarm, everything still safe. Thanks for the help.